# Calendar 8.0 reminders in GMT

Tags: calendar, reminders

I have Calendar set to my time zone. However, reminder popups still give the time in GMT. How can this be adjusted?

[image: Screen shot of reminder popup]

Answer (score 1):

Try going into (Calendar) Preferences... -> Advanced and turn on "Time Zone Support"

[image: Settings]

You will se a new menu item where you can change Calendar's time zone:
[image]

Comment: Sincere thanks! I thought I already had that set properly. But I re-did the settings and will try again.